# vue - how do I add my prop value as a class value in the template?

Tags: vue.js

How do I add my value of the prop thrID as a class value in the template?

thrID is passed in as **my1value**

```
<template>
  <div v-bind:class="['hhhhh',thrID]">
    test {{thrID}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>


export default {
  name: 'bottom',
  components: {

  },
  props:["thrID"]
}
</script>

<style scoped>
  .bottom {
    background: yellow;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

it renders

```
<div data-v-10e356bb="" data-v-7ba5bd90="" class="hhhhh">
  test my1value
</div>
```

I want it to have a class like this

```
<div data-v-10e356bb="" data-v-7ba5bd90="" class="hhhhh my1value">
  test my1value
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works fine.  See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y3mwcqf9/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily add custom classes by binding a string, array or object to the class attribute. You start of by using the `v-bind` or `:` syntax to bind a variable to the `class` attribute:

```
<template>
  <div :class="classes">
    <!-- Magic! -->
  </div>
</template>
```

Then, in our export component we can do several things. The most versatile option is to use an object. If the value of a key is truthy, that class is applied. If the value is falsy, it will not be applied. We use the `[ keyName ]: value` syntax to add `this.thrID` as a key to our object.

```
export default {
  props: {
    thrID: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    classes () {
      return {
        hhhhh: true,
        [this.thrID]: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Similarly, you can return an array:

```
classes () {
  return [
    'hhhhh',
    this.thrID
  ]
}
```

Or you can create some string with classes:

```
classes () {
  return `hhhhh {$this.thrID}`
}
```